# How to suppress parts in Orchard based on zone

Tags: orchardcms-1.8

How can suppress the Tags Part of the summary How2 content type when it appears in the aside second.  I have the following code in my placement.info file but that affects all summarized How2 content types.

```
<Match ContentType="How2"> 
   <Match DisplayType="Summary">
      <Place Fields_Common_Text-ToolsRequired="-"/>
      <Place Parts_Tags_ShowTags="Content:9.9"/>
   </Match>
</Match>
```

I would only like to suppress the tags only if they appear in the asidesecond zone which is a projection widget.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same question while developing a theme for my first Orchard website. It isn't possible to suppress the same ContentType with the same DisplayType based on the zone. You will have to create an alternate at a higher level or do some programming. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31202492/orchard-alternates-for-different-zones/31305863#31305863). I had the question answered on the [Orchard discussion forum](http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/640945#post1433522).

Hope that helps.